# How can i get connected teacher count and subject count according to student id in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Here that i need to get count of connected teachers and connected subjects according to students_id using reservation table's data.
[image: Reservations table with teacher data and subject data]

In case student_id = 1 provide the teacher count = 2 beacuse of connected teacher_ids are 1 and 2 only. And then student_id = 1 provide the subject count = 3 beacuse of connected subject_ids are 3,1 and 2 only. How can i implement this function in laravel ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can do something like that:

```
DB::table('reservations')
->where('student_id', $student_id)
->distinct('teacher_id')
->count('teacher_id');
```

This gets the reservations for **Student** with id: `$student_id` and then counts all distinct teacher ids.